# Geoserver WFS- GetFeatureRequest - All Items filtered out?

Tags: geoserver

I am using geoserver to cascade a WFS which is working fine. Inside of my script I am manipulating the getCapabilities-Response to use my script again for the GetFeature request as the initial WFS is not working if directly implemented into geoserver.

I am using geoserver 2.21.2

The GetFeatureInfo returns an empty featureCollection. Probably due to the numerous lines like those:

```
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AA_Lebenszeitintervall. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AA_Lebenszeitintervall. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the schema/namespaces or something else. Due to this lines in the error message:

```
4 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [data.ows] - Executed request to URL: MYPHPSCRIPT?PROPERTYNAME=inversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_Darstellung%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_LTO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PTO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_FPO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_KPO_3D%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_LPO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PPO%2CtraegtBeiZu%2CistAbgeleitetAus%2CinversZu_hatDirektUnten%2ChatDirektUnten%2Cposition%2CinversZu_verweistAuf%2Cflurstueckskennzeichen%2Cflurnummer%2Cflurstuecksfolge%2CabweichenderRechtszustand%2CzweifelhafterFlurstuecksnachweis%2Crechtsbehelfsverfahren%2Cobjektkoordinaten%2CzeitpunktDerEntstehung%2CinversZu_beziehtSichAuf%2CistGebucht%2CzeigtAuf%2CweistAuf%2CgehoertAnteiligZu%2CbeziehtSichAufFlurstueck&FILTER=%3Cfes%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Afes%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Ffes%2F2.0%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2F3.2%22%3E%3Cfes%3ABBOX%3E%3Cfes%3AValueReference%3Eposition%3C%2Ffes%3AValueReference%3E%3Cgml%3AEnvelope+srsDimension%3D%222%22+srsName%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2Fsrs%2Fepsg.xml%2325833%22%3E%3Cgml%3AlowerCorner%3E399414.297589+5830669.894315%3C%2Fgml%3AlowerCorner%3E%3Cgml%3AupperCorner%3E399418.136627+5830673.733353%3C%2Fgml%3AupperCorner%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3C%2Ffes%3ABBOX%3E%3C%2Ffes%3AFilter%3E&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fgml%2Bxml%3B+version%3D3.2&SRSNAME=urn%3Aogc%3Adef%3Acrs%3AEPSG%3A%3A25833&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=adv%3AAX_Flurstueck&SERVICE=WFS
24 Nov 11:58:16 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 WARN   [xsd.impl] - Error parsing: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd ==> jar:file:/D:/geoserver/GeoServer%202.21.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-gml3-27.2.jar!/org/geotools/gml3/v3_2/gml.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not resolve schema location: ../gco/basicTypes.xsd to physical location.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not locate schema for: ../gco/basicTypes.xsd.
24 Nov 11:58:16 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not resolve schema location: ../gmd/metadataApplication.xsd to physical location.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not locate schema for: ../gmd/metadataApplication.xsd.
```

I can change the reponse that geoserver gets using string manipulation etc., i just need to know how.

```
24 Nov 11:58:16 TRACE  [wfs.internal] - Response head:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gml:FeatureCollection gml:id="collection.0" xmlns="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
<gml:lowerCorner>399387.394 5830557.36</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>399475.508 5830679.215</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<adv_AX_Flurstueck gml:id="DEBBAL600002LyxJ">
<gml:identifier codeSpace="http://www.adv-online.de/">urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL600002LyxJ</gml:identifier>
<lebenszeitintervall>
<AA_Lebenszeitintervall>
<beginnt>2017-04-21T12:34:03Z</beginnt>
</AA_Lebenszeitintervall>
</lebenszeitintervall>
<modellart>
<AA_Modellart>
<advStandardModell>DLKM</advStandardModell>
</AA_Modellart>
</modellart>
<anlass>300500</anlass>
<zeigtAufExternes>
<AA_Fachdatenverbindung>
<art>urn:adv:fachdatenverbindung:AA_Antrag</art>
<fachdatenobjekt>
<AA_Fachdatenobjekt>
<uri>urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL0100096uY2</uri>
</AA_Fachdatenobjekt>
</fachdatenobjekt>
</AA_Fachdatenverbindung>
</zeigtAufExternes>
<inversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PTO xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL600002LArx"/>
<position>
<gml:Polygon gml:id="o11001.id.346133103.position.Geom_0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:posList>399387.394 5830673.446 399393.111 5830664.334 399403.787 5830645.689 399422.01 5830617.937 399437.975 5830590.404 399454.026 5830557.36 399475.508 5830557.468 399446.758 5830679.215 399387.394 5830673.446</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
</position>
<gemarkung>
<AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
<land>12</land>
<gemarkungsnummer>1647</gemarkungsnummer>
</AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
</gemarkung>
<flurstuecksnummer>
<adv_AX_Flurstuecksnummer>
<zaehler>24</zaehler>
</adv_AX_Flurstuecksnummer>
</flurstuecksnummer>
<flurstueckskennzeichen>12164700700024______</flurstueckskennzeichen>
<amtlicheFlaeche uom="m2">4904.00</amtlicheFlaeche>
<flurnummer>7</flurnummer>
<abweichenderRechtszustand>false</abweichenderRechtszustand>
<zeitpunktDerEntstehung>1998-01-01</zeitpunktDerEntstehung>
<gemeindezugehoerigkeit>
<AX_Gemeindekennzeichen>
<land>12</land>
<regierungsbezirk>0</regierungsbezirk>
<kreis>60</kreis>
<gemeinde>181</gemeinde>
</AX_Gemeindekennzeichen>
</gemeindezugehoerigkeit>
<zustaendigeStelle>
<AX_Dienststelle_Schluessel>
<land>12</land>
<stelle>3065</stelle>
</AX_Dienststelle_Schluessel>
</zustaendigeStelle>
<istGebucht xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL010009p3i3"/>
<zeigtAuf xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DEBBAL600002LMED"/>
</adv_AX_Flurstueck>
</gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [data.ows] - Executed request to URL: MYPHPSCRIPT?PROPERTYNAME=inversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_Darstellung%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_LTO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PTO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_FPO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_KPO_3D%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_LPO%2CinversZu_dientZurDarstellungVon_AP_PPO%2CtraegtBeiZu%2CistAbgeleitetAus%2CinversZu_hatDirektUnten%2ChatDirektUnten%2Cposition%2CinversZu_verweistAuf%2Cflurstueckskennzeichen%2Cflurnummer%2Cflurstuecksfolge%2CabweichenderRechtszustand%2CzweifelhafterFlurstuecksnachweis%2Crechtsbehelfsverfahren%2Cobjektkoordinaten%2CzeitpunktDerEntstehung%2CinversZu_beziehtSichAuf%2CistGebucht%2CzeigtAuf%2CweistAuf%2CgehoertAnteiligZu%2CbeziehtSichAufFlurstueck&FILTER=%3Cfes%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Afes%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Ffes%2F2.0%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2F3.2%22%3E%3Cfes%3ABBOX%3E%3Cfes%3AValueReference%3Eposition%3C%2Ffes%3AValueReference%3E%3Cgml%3AEnvelope+srsDimension%3D%222%22+srsName%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2Fsrs%2Fepsg.xml%2325833%22%3E%3Cgml%3AlowerCorner%3E399414.297589+5830669.894315%3C%2Fgml%3AlowerCorner%3E%3Cgml%3AupperCorner%3E399418.136627+5830673.733353%3C%2Fgml%3AupperCorner%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3C%2Ffes%3ABBOX%3E%3C%2Ffes%3AFilter%3E&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fgml%2Bxml%3B+version%3D3.2&SRSNAME=urn%3Aogc%3Adef%3Acrs%3AEPSG%3A%3A25833&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=adv%3AAX_Flurstueck&SERVICE=WFS
24 Nov 11:58:16 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 WARN   [xsd.impl] - Error parsing: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/Fachschema.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd ==> jar:file:/D:/geoserver/GeoServer%202.21.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-gml3-27.2.jar!/org/geotools/gml3/v3_2/gml.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not resolve schema location: ../gco/basicTypes.xsd to physical location.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not locate schema for: ../gco/basicTypes.xsd.
24 Nov 11:58:16 INFO   [xsd.impl] - https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not resolve schema location: ../gmd/metadataApplication.xsd to physical location.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - Could not locate schema for: ../gmd/metadataApplication.xsd.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - schema specified by parser configuration not found, supplementing...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}adv_AX_Flurstueck. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}lebenszeitintervall. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}lebenszeitintervall. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}lebenszeitintervall. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
[.....]
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Parsing unknown attribute: {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href
[...]
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurstuecksnummer. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurstuecksnummer. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurstuecksnummer. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}adv_AX_Flurstuecksnummer. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}adv_AX_Flurstuecksnummer. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}adv_AX_Flurstuecksnummer. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zaehler. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zaehler. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zaehler. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurstueckskennzeichen. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurstueckskennzeichen. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurstueckskennzeichen. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}amtlicheFlaeche. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}amtlicheFlaeche. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}amtlicheFlaeche. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Parsing unknown attribute: uom
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurnummer. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurnummer. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}flurnummer. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}abweichenderRechtszustand. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}abweichenderRechtszustand. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}abweichenderRechtszustand. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeitpunktDerEntstehung. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeitpunktDerEntstehung. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeitpunktDerEntstehung. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}gemeindezugehoerigkeit. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}gemeindezugehoerigkeit. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}gemeindezugehoerigkeit. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Gemeindekennzeichen. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Gemeindekennzeichen. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Gemeindekennzeichen. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}land. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}land. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}land. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}regierungsbezirk. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}regierungsbezirk. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}regierungsbezirk. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}kreis. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}kreis. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}kreis. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}gemeinde. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}gemeinde. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}gemeinde. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zustaendigeStelle. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zustaendigeStelle. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zustaendigeStelle. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Dienststelle_Schluessel. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Dienststelle_Schluessel. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}AX_Dienststelle_Schluessel. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}land. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}land. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}land. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}stelle. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}stelle. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}stelle. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}istGebucht. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}istGebucht. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}istGebucht. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Parsing unknown attribute: {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeigtAuf. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeigtAuf. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0}zeigtAuf. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Parsing unknown attribute: {http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [renderer.label] - TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [renderer.label] - PAINTED LINE LABELS : 0
24 Nov 11:58:16 DEBUG  [renderer.label] - REMAINING LINE LABELS : 0
```